# Syntax for SVG <image> element using a local resource

Tags: image, svg, resources, local

Is there a difference in the syntax when using the SVG-image-element with a local source (e.g. `C:\image.png`) and a source on the internet (e.g `http://www.google.de/intl/de_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif`)?

My Problem is that the following works:

```
<image x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="http://www.google.de/intl/de_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif">
</image>
```

and with the following, i'm just getting a white page:

```
<image x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" href="C:\google.png"></image>
```

Answer (score 6):

Solved the problem...:

```
<image x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="file://C:\google.png"></image>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `"file:///c:/google.png"`?

Comment: i tried: 
"<image x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" href="file:///C:\google.png"></image>"

but still doesn't work!

Comment: You may have to replace the backslashes with forward slashes: `"file://C:/Documents and Settings/Benjbra/workspace/PythTest/google.png"`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows_2 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The path you should use for macOS is:

`file:///Users/aizat/.../image.png`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try use the file:// protocol

Take the remote page and do a save page as on chrome and see what manipulation he do to the image tag.