# D3 append image but from a local directory

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I'm using this to append an image in a node and it works great:

````
 ```this.node.append("svg:image")
        .attr("class", "lock")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr('x',5)         
        .attr('y',-15)         
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .attr("xlink:href", "https://example.com/png");```
````

The problem is that I want to use a local img as a src of the img I can't get it to load.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456007/syntax-for-svg-image-element-using-a-local-resource.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the team using word press so I had to give it a different path:

```
this.node.append("image")
    //...
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/lock.png");
```