# Javascript d3 insert image from local file

Tags: javascript, sql, d3.js

**Update**: I changed the last two lines to the following.

```
.append('img')
    .attr('src','images/testimage.png')
```

But the image is not appearing. There is a broken image in its place so I believe either the file path syntax is incorrect or there's something else I'm not seeing.

**Original Post**

I'm having trouble rendering an image stored in my local directory via js. The last 2-3 lines of code is where the issue is. I'm not 100% sure if that's the correct notation for the file path (I think it is based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456007/syntax-for-svg-image-element-using-a-local-resource).

```
d3.select("#solve")
  .append('h2')
  .text("Solve.")

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){

    d3.select("#question")
          .append('p')
          .text(response[i]['id'])
          .append('p')
          .text(response[i]['statement'])
          .append('li')
          .text(response[i]['a1'])
          .append('li')
          .text(response[i]['a2'])
          .append('li')
          .text(response[i]['a3'])
          .append('li')
          .text(response[i]['a4'])
          .append('li')
          .text(response[i]['a5'])
          .append('div')
          .append('svg:image')
          .attr('href', 'file://C:/Users/Bryant/Documents/GitHub/ACT/static/js/images/testimage.png')


}
```

};

When i inspect the HTML element, this is what I get. However no image appears on the webpage.

```
<image href="file://C:/Users/Bryant/Documents/GitHub/ACT/static/js/images/testimage.png"></image>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: While there may be other issues with your code (`.append` appends a child, not a sibling, I don't think you want to nest your `li`s (though you might), and loops aren't the standard method to append things with d3), it appears as though you are appending an svg <image> to a <div>, you should probably be appending an html <img> with an attribute for `src` rather than `href`

Comment: Thx Andrew, please see update if you can spare more knowledge.

Comment: I would try running it in a simple web server - some web browsers don't load local content due to security restrictions.

Comment: All your suggestions worked. I ended up using the src attribute and hosting pictures on Amazon AWS. Good news is I ended up with a better conceptual understanding of how js works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to add an image element to your div selection using d3js. You don't need to append an svg in order to do this, you can directly append your img element to your div:

```js
const domElement = d3.select("#question");
const imagePath = 'https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22018/screenshots/2456036/d3_1x.png';
domElement.append('img').attr('src', imagePath);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Comment: Thx Sean, please see the updated post as I've run into another issue.

Comment: If the image shows up as a broken link, this means the browser cannot find the image at the given path. In your case, it looks like 'images/testimage.png' may not be a valid location.

If you are using a js library like angular or express to serve up your files, you may need to ensure that the relative pathing is correct. Otherwise, you could try serving up static files from an absolute path. Or, if you can host your images in the cloud somewhere, you could directly reference the http location like in my example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.append('svg:image')
.attr('href', 'file://C:/Users/Bryant/Documents/GitHub/ACT/static/js/images/testimage.png')
```

use this (xlink:href attribute in place of href) :

```
.append('svg:image')
.attr("xlink:href", function() {return "file://C:/Users/Bryant/Documents/GitHub/ACT/static/js/images/testimage.png"})
.attr('width', "50")
.attr('height', "50")
```