# Insert local SVG image using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I can easily insert an SVG image using D3.js using an URL, like this:

```
var img = g.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/4/5/a/1331068897296558865Sitting%20Racoon.svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("x", 228)
    .attr("y",53);
```

However, I have looked everywhere online and tried everything I could think of, I have not been able to **do the same using a local image reference** (absolute or relative path) and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

my version (working):

CSS:

```
   iframe {
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     border-width: 0px;
     /* background-color: #B0B0B0; */
     border: none;
    }
```

JS:

```
(function () {
  // Prevent White Flash While iFrame Loads. Prevent variables from being global.
  // 1. Inject CSS which makes iframe invisible 
  var div = document.createElement('div'),
      ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0]
         || document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);
  // 2. When window loads, remove that CSS, making iframe visible again
    window.onload = function() {
      div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="image\hour-glass.svg" scrolling="no" align="bottom"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be useful SO link
[Javascript d3 insert image from local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847834/javascript-d3-insert-image-from-local-file)

Comment: I've already tried the line from this question:
.attr("xlink:href", function() {return "file://C:/Users/Bryant/Documents/GitHub/ACT/static/js/images/testimage.png"})

But with no success